# cupy indexing is slow

Tags: python-3.x, performance, cupy

I am trying to perform operations on a large cupy array of size 16000. I find mathematical operations such as addition to be quite fast, but indexing using boolean masks to be relatively slow. For example, the following code:

```
import cupy as cp
arr = cp.random.normal(0, 1, 16000)
%timeit arr * 5
%timeit arr > 0.4
%timeit arr[arr > 0.4] = 0
```

gives me the output:

```
28 µs ± 950 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
26.5 µs ± 1.61 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
104 µs ± 2.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Any reason why the final indexing is at least twice as slow? I assumed that multiplication should be slower than setting array elements.

**Update**: This is not true for numpy indexing. Changing the cupy array to numpy, I get:

```
6.71 µs ± 373 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
4.42 µs ± 56.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
5.39 µs ± 29.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the 3rd case, `cupy` is composing the result via a sequence of operations: `cupy_greater`, `cupy_copy`, `inclusive_scan_kernel`, `inclusive_scan_kernel`, `add_scan_blocked_sum_kernel`, `CUDA memcpy DtoH` (perhaps to provide the number of elements that need to be set to zero), `CUDA memset` (perhaps to set an array to zero), and finally `cupy_scatter_update_mask` (to scatter the zeros to their correct locations, perhaps).

This is a considerably more complex sequence than `arr*5`, which seems to run a single `cupy_multiply` under the hood. You can probably do better with a [`cupy` user-defined kernel](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/tutorial/kernel.html):

```
import cupy as cp
clamp_generic = cp.ElementwiseKernel(
        'T x, T c',
        'T y',
        'y = (y > x)?c:y',
        'clamp_generic')
arr = cp.random.normal(0, 1, 16000)
clamp_generic(0.4, 0, arr)
```

Comment: Thank you -- that resolved it. Running 'timeit' on 'clamp_generic' gives me just 6.12 µs ± 149 ns per loop.